# How to Convert cummulative frequency values to normal frequency

Tags: pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum, datetimeindex

It is an Pandas Data frame with dateTime index. This the Cumulative data observation daily frequency, I need to convert this data points to normal frequency. I need to convert the cummulative values to normal values for each and every day.

It is an Pandas Data frame with dateTime index Cumulative values

[image: It is an Pandas Data frame with dateTime index Cumulative values]

Example how the output looks

[image: Example how the output looks]

Comment: take a `.diff()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.